# Change AI Enemy Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, 2d, game-development

Currently, I'm making a game in unity, and I made a simple script to make the enemy follow the player but I can't change the animation of the enemy to the other side

gameplay:

[image]

EnemyController.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
  [Header("References")]
  private Animator animator;
  // The target to follow.
  private Transform target;
  private Rigidbody2D rb;

  [Header("Movement")]
  public float speed;
  public float range;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    target = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>().transform;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    FollowPlayer();
  }

  private void FollowPlayer()
  {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your enemy's Animator controller, also show which animation is triggered with the "isRunning" flag, because from the script there isn't any indication for switching the animations

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by using blend tree

Blend Tree:

[image: Blend Tree]

Script:

```cs
private void FollowPlayer()
{
  animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
  animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", target.position.x - transform.position.x);
  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```